# Gatling - show failed requests only after max retry

Tags: performance, scala, load, gatling

In my test scenario I'm polling user session for possible responses. due to the product behavior' this is normal to receive 503 several times before receiving response and this is the reason why I'm retrying  up to 5 times.

```
tryMax(5){
      exec(http("Poll user")
        .get("/something.html")
        .queryParamMap(Map("NC" -> "true", "data" -> "true", "v" -> "1"))
        .check(
          status.is(200))
      )}
```

Now' when I look at statistics I see 4 failed requests:

```
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 80     / done:0
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=1771   KO=4     )
> Form Login                                               (OK=80     KO=0     )
> **********************                                   (OK=80     KO=0     )
> Agent Base                                               (OK=80     KO=0     )
> Login                                                    (OK=80     KO=0     )
> Set availability to Online                               (OK=80     KO=0     )
> Poll session                                             (OK=1291   KO=4     )
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> status.find.is(200), but actually found 503                         4 (100.0%)
================================================================================
```

I would like to see a KO statistics only for requests that failed after 5 reties, because from my point of view, if it succeeded with less then 5 retries it wouldn't mean that the request failed.

Can I do so?

Comment: At best, you could make the first 503 tentatives marked as OK.
But you won't be able to make them silent.

Comment: Thank you for response, but will retry on 503, if I make it as OK?

Comment: You'd have to manually mark the Session as failed (Session.markAsFailed)

Comment: Did you end up figuring out the solution with the suggestions?  Is the idea to mark each try in the loop a manually overridden "Success" in the session, and then finally mark them as failed manually? I wish there was a way to configure this to do that with a flag instead @StephaneLandelle